# Uninstall flash debugger

Tags: flash

I installed the debug version of Flash Player to do some development work.  I would now like to uninstall the developers version and revert back to the standard version.  How?

I am running Windows 8.1 x64 with IE 11.

My system shows "You have version 14,0,0,176 installed" from the Flash Player page.

I have used the following link to uninstall both manually and with the download program.  When doing the manual version I search the C drive and unregistered about five different copies of both 32 and 64 bit version.

https://helpx.adobe.com/flex/kb/uninstalling-flash-player-debugger.html

I have tried installing from the following link but it says the update does not apply to my system.

https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-issues-windows-8.html#main-pars_header_0

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get an answer on the Adobe site, basically go to the Add Remove Programs, Select View Installed Updates, and uninstall the debugging update.

Know they said to use the KB number of the update but being as it had been a long time and I had no clue what the KB number was I just entered debug in the search bar.  The flash debugger can up and I clicked it.

Note when first uninstalled you have to reboot and the flash version number is rather old, most likely the default that came with windows.  Just do windows update and it will bring it up to the latest version.